# Adding manually compiled SMACC2 packages files to /opt/foxy folder

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

I am interested in utilizing the "SMACC2" library, a versatile event-driven, asynchronous, behavioral state machine library designed for real-time ROS 2 applications. While I am aware that official support for the Foxy distribution has concluded, I am currently working on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

To address this, I have successfully built the "foxy" branch of the SMACC2 library from the GitHub repository by following the provided instructions [https://github.com/robosoft-ai/SMACC2](https://stackoverflow.com).

My workspace, located at `~/workspace/foxy_ws`, consists of the `build`, `install`, and `log` folders, in addition to the `src` folder containing the downloaded source files from the aforementioned GitHub page. Now, my objective is to copy or move each package from the `install` directory to the `/opt/foxy` directory, ensuring that all the subfolders (i.e., `include`, `lib`, `share`) are correctly distributed within the `/opt/foxy` directory.

Here is the current structure of my workspace:

```
user@user:~/workspace/foxy_ws$ ls
build  install  log  src
```

and `install` includes:

```
user@user:~/workspace/foxy_ws/install$ ls -l

... COLCON_IGNORE
... local_setup.bash
... local_setup.ps1
... local_setup.sh
... _local_setup_util_ps1.py
... _local_setup_util_sh.py
... local_setup.zsh
... ros_timer_client
... setup.bash
... setup.ps1
... setup.sh
... setup.zsh
... smacc2
... smacc2_msgs
... sm_atomic
... sm_atomic_mode_states
```

I am uncertain about how to incorporate packages such as `ros_timer_client`, `smacc2`, `smacc2_msgs`, `sm_atomic`, and `sm_atomic_mode_states` into any workspace without being confined to `~/workspace/foxy_ws` in my implementations.

If anyone has encountered a similar question or has insights into this matter, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. I have conducted a search on Stack Overflow but have not found a satisfactory answer.

Thank you in advance.

I have tried to run the following command in the `~/workspace/foxy_ws`

```
sudo colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-base /opt/foxy
```

and it destroyed the destroy the integrity of ros2 framework. I could not run the fundamental `ros2 run` commands after that.